# Guardar variables (GET) durante todo el ciclo de vida en Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-8

Necesito almacenar una serie de variables que vienen de una petición `GET` en una sola cadena cifrada en **AES-256-CBC**.

Por ejemplo:

> http://localhost:8080/test.php/?fas=MUhBRXNWMXBuK252dkRHL05NUjU5M1ltUzM0cFY4d2duZzlzNG0wS2s1d1dQN3RNNmVGT2RhR1NwWVBNUTdoVGdXUC9aR0lFZnFZZ2drMXkxVUZsYUYwRWh3UXFvdTlkL21QQmtBOTBYNmU2UUVxcm1pOEVQQmEzbDNqNFpkcEdwMzU5Mk9mRkJaQnFRYlZxdHAxUXhkRWlMMk9pVVRNZzJ2emp3ZEQxcmZBPQ

Este parámetro **fas**, lo desencripto en mi controlador y se convierte en varias variables (con contenido distinto por usuario).

La cosa es que estas variables no las uso hasta que el usuario no pasa por un proceso de *login/register* y de momento estaba probando a pasarlas por las distintas partes de la aplicación como parámetros hasta que llegue el momento de tratarlas, pero me parece muy engorroso.

¿Hay alguna forma de almacenarlas y usarlas cuando corresponda? ¿Quizás como variables globales?

Comment: ¿Y con variables de $_SESSION no te sirve?  No hace falta que este logeado para usarlas, tan solo que exista una sesión abierta por alli donde pase, y cuando haga el login/register la buscas alli y sacas las variables que deseas.

Comment: Creo que no me sirve y me explico. Las peticiones GET no las hacen directamente un usuario si no que los usuarios se conectan a un router y es éste el que crea la query, por lo tanto, a vistas del servidor web, siempre es el mismo "usuario"

Comment: Por lo que estoy leyendo podría probar a usar variables de $_SESSION por cada request, así en realidad da igual que el usuario sea el mismo, cada petición GET que haga será una sesión distinta, ¿verdad?

Comment: No se que decirte, en ese contexto pruébalo y nos cuentas. Otra opción seria almacenar los datos en los navegadores de los usuarios, mediante el uso de javascript y localStorage o sessionStorage, y a menos que se limpien la cache permaneceran almacenadas en su cache y podrás acceder a ellas con javascript

Comment: La opción de javascript la tengo descartada 100% y al final creo que voy a tener que enviar a cada vista, ruta o controlador las variables que necesito... :( GRACIAS